# Value not saving in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

```js
const serverS = await server.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id });
serverS.settings[1]["links"] = true;
serverS.save()
```

The code I use ^^^^

So when it saves the changes I check the database using MongoDB compass I don't see the change appearing in the array object

schema if needed to resolve problem

```
const ServerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    guildID: { type: String },
    settings: {
        type: Array, default: [
            {
            //Some other stuff
            },
            {
                links: false,
            },
            {
                prefix: ",",
            }
        ]
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way on how to update a part of a array using javascript and mongoose:

**For example:**

```js
collection name
||    array name                   values
||    ||          id               ||
\/    \/          \/               \/
data.settings.set(0, {lang: "english", prefix: "!"})
data.save()
```

**Saved Data:**

```json
"settings": [
   {
      "lang": "english",
      "prefix": ",",
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` method returns a promise, so you should `await` the save as a following:

```
const serverS = await server.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id });
serverS.settings[1]["links"] = true;
const dataSaved = await serverS.save(); //if the save fail will throw an error 
console.log({dataSaved}) //to verify the data was saved
```

Comment: Still didn't work, I checked the time that document was "saved" and it didn't change

Comment: Do you checked it out what `save()` method return?

Comment: Yes I checked it and alll it showed was [object] where the values suppose to be

Comment: could you show your schema?

Comment: i just put the schema in the question